# Is there a way to view data frames nice in Wing Personal 7.0?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, wing-ide

I want to view my data frames in a nice/pretty way like in Jupyter.

I updated from Wing IDE 101 6.0 to Wing Personal 7.0, but did not see a difference in how my data frames are displayed.
Also, I pip installed IPython and used the display function, but my data frames did not appear any different.
I have also tried packages such as tabulate, but I am looking more to replicate the dataframe viewers in Jupyter without having to use Jupyter to run my code.

Answer (score 0):

The new array and dataframe viewer is only in Wing Pro, and not Wing 101 or Wing Personal.